# Asp.net Hidden field not having value in code behind, but *is* retaining value after postbacks

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my ASCX, I have an asp.net hidden field defined as `<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnNewAsset" runat="server" />`.

In the Code Behind I have the following code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _service = new ArticleDataService(PortalId);

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string rawId = Request[ArticleQueryParams.ArticleId];
            DisplayArticleDetails(rawId);
        }

        if (hdnNewAsset.Value.Trim() != string.Empty)
            ProcessNewAsset();
    }
```

Now, in my frontend, I have a javascript function to react to an event and set the hidden field and trigger a postback:

```
function assetSelected(assetGuid) {
    $('input[id*="hdnNewAsset"]').val(assetGuid);
    __doPostBack()
}
```

What's happening is that my hidden field is being set in the markup (chrome shows `[
<input type=​"hidden" name=​"dnn$ctr466$Main$ctl00$hdnNewAsset" id=​"dnn_ctr466_Main_ctl00_hdnNewAsset" value=​"98d88e72-088c-40a4-9022-565a53dc33c4">​
]` for `$('input[id*="hdnNewAsset"]')`).

However, when the postback occurs, `hdnNewAsset.Value` is an empty string.

What's even more puzzling is that at the beginning of `Page_Load` `Request.Params["dnn$ctr466$Main$ctl00$hdnNewAsset"]` shows `98d88e72-088c-40a4-9022-565a53dc33c4`, and after the postback my hidden field has the same value (so the hidden field is persisting across postbacks), yet I cannot access this value via `hdnNewAsset.Value`.

Can anyone see what I"m doing wrong?

Comment: Where is the code that assigns the `hdnNewAsset`? It it protected by `IsPostBack` check?

Comment: At what point in the postback cycle are you trying to access the value of the field? If you're doing it before the view state is loaded then you will get an empty string. Also, what browser are you using? I've seen issues like this in Chrome (but only in Chrome). Try another browser and see if you get the same result.

Comment: @Kami: Nothing is setting the value, I'ts only getting set by the javascript I posted on the frontend

Comment: @BrianDriscoll, I am trying to access the variable where it's show in `Page_Load`.  At the beginning of `Page_Load` (verified viat watches) `hdnNewAsset.Value` is empty

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out the the issue.

The issue is that the code posted above was part of an ASCX user control.  That user control was being loaded dynamically into an asp.net placeholder during the `Page_Load` event of the parent control.

Therefore, it seems that since both of these calls were in `Page_Load` of their respective calls, the inner control did not have it's values bound in the inner control's `page_load`.  Modifying it so my inner control is loaded in `Page_Init` instead of `Page_Load` fixed all bindings.

Not sure if I wrote that in a way that makes sense to the general public.

---

**Edit**: It seems [this part of the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx) is relevant to my issue:

> If controls are created dynamically at run time or declaratively within templates of data-bound controls, their events are initially not synchronized with those of other controls on the page. For example, for a control that is added at run time, the Init and Load events might occur much later in the page life cycle than the same events for controls created declaratively. Therefore, from the time that they are instantiated, dynamically added controls and controls in templates raise their events one after the other until they have caught up to the event during which it was added to the Controls collection.